# How to find whether a certain file is available in the system path?

Tags: powershell

My Powershell script must be run from a VS command prompt, and I want to verity that by checking that  msbuild.exe is in path. I managed to do it using where.exe:

```
where.exe msbuild.exe > $null
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    throw "BuildAll must be run from ""Developer Command Prompt for VS2012"" shortcut."
}
```

However, this doesn't feel like "the Powershell way" - is there a Powershell-native way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if the `msbuild.exe` must be in the same folder as the script is

```
   if ( TEST-PATH (JOIN-PATH (Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition) "msbuild.exe " ))
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

If you want check if  `build.exe` is available as command (any available path from $env:path) you can do:

```
if ([bool](Get-Command "msbuild.exe" -ea silentlycontinue)) 
{ 
  ...
}
```

Comment: The `Get-Command` solution is the thing. I noticed that I don't need the cast to `[bool]` - I basically just do:
`if (!(Get-Command "msbuild.exe" ...)) { throw "BuildAll must be run..." }`

Comment: @Jonathan Glad to help! I don't like throw an exception but it can work! ;)