# How to find whether a non-command file is available in the system path?

Tags: powershell

I want to test whether a certain file is in the system PATH. in cmd, I can do it using `where.exe my.dll`.

How do I do it in PowerShell?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687116/552510) suggests `Get-Command`, which works only for executables - I want to find DLLs as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gci ($env:Path).split(';') -Filter *.dll

Comment: Much shorter than what i was doing. Keep forgetting that `-Path` accepts string arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could search the path for it as follows:

```
$ENV:Path -split ';' | % { if ( test-path "$_\my.dll") { write-host $_ } }
```

The `PATH` variable is semi-colon separated, so you can split the string using `;` as the delimiter, then loop over each location with the file you're seeking appended. If a location is printed, your file will be on the path.

Comment: You beat me by a minute. I did away with the ForEach-Object in favour of where which just outputs the paths without Write-Host. This might have an issue if the path in `PATH` had a trailing backslash?